# C# method for finding Book in list, and removing a Book from the list

Tags: c#, list, methods

I have to make a Library class that has a list of Books with a Title, Author, and ID#. I have to make methods to add books, find books by title, display all books, and remove books.

Is my addBook() method correct?

I have an error with my findBook() method saying to create a constructor in the Book class but there already is a constructor.

Also I really have no idea where to begin to remove a Book from the list... I have looked up solutions for removing items from a list but I don't really get how I would implement it in my program.

I don't understand a lot of things because my first college course CSE 1301 was terrible, and I am in 1302 having to learn basic things plus the more complex things.

```
public class Library
{
    public string name;
    public List<Book> books = new List<Book>();

    public void addBook(string title, string author)
    {
        int bookQuantity;

        string btitle;
        string bauthor;

        bookQuantity = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        for (int x = 0; x <= bookQuantity; x++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Title:");
            btitle = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Enter Author:");
            bauthor = Console.ReadLine();

            books.Add(new Book(btitle, bauthor));
        }
    }

    public void findBook()
    {
        var obj = new Book();
        obj.ID = "xy";
        string id = obj.ID;

        Book result = books.Find(x => x.ID == "xy");
    }

    public void displayBooks()
    {
        foreach (Book b in books)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(b.ToString());
        }
    }

    public void removeBook()
    {

    }

    public Library()
    {

    }
}

public class Book
{
    public string title;
    public string author;
    public int id;
    static int isbn;

    public string ID { get; set; }

    public void assignID()
    {
        id = isbn;
        isbn++;
    }

    public Book(string title, string author)
    {
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Title: " + title, "\nAuthor: " + author, "\nISBN: " + id);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the EXACT error u get and on which line? because to me it looks like you're not making a new instance of your class,instead ur calling book.book() and that method has 2 arguments in its parenthesis...

Comment: change your FindBook() method to this and also change the void to book so that it can actually find a book and return it, and Your code will Compile. at least the error is fixed that way...        public Book findBook()
            {
                string id = "xy";
                return books.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == id);
            }

Comment: @Niklas: that will only ever find one book.

Comment: then make it return a list ! thats not hard?...     public List<Book> findBook()
            {
                string id = "xy";
                return books.Where(x => x.ID == id).ToList();
            }

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `new Book()` in `findBook` at all. Also, `int`s are not large enough to store an ISBN and you can't create ISBNs from sequential integers. If you want to store sequential integers don't call them ISBNs. You also never assign `Book.ID` so comparing against it is useless. Making all properties of your class mutable is also problematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is not correct. It has some flaws:
1. It calls I/O methods to get information from the user. But that's not what this function ought to be doing. Its job is to add a book to a library. It should be given information about the book via parameters, and then use that information to construct a new book and add it to the internal list. Nothing else. You actually have most of the code for that, so fixing your problem would be along the lines of deleting a bunch of code and reworking what is left.
2. The function says "add book", but it actually adds multiple books, based on user input, and ignores the arguments passed to it. A function should say what it does, and then actually do it.

The same goes for your `findBook()` code, which neither takes any parameters (how does it know what to find?) nor returns anything (whatever it finds is ignored and can't be used by any other code).

There are many other issues with your code, but I am focusing on the question you asked, about `addBook()`. In general, though, if you make functions that do what they say, take parameters and return things, and don't do extra work, or do I/O, then you will probably be able to improve the code on your own. Please let me know if you have follow up questions.

Comment: I should have mentioned that my assignment requires a user to add a book manually from the console. Does that change things? Sorry for not being more clear

Comment: @JustinL: in fact, it doesn't. The code that loads book information will be somewhere else. For a simple assignment like this, that code will probably be in `Main()`. Once information is collected from the user, you can call the `addBook()` method on an instance of the `Library` class. The `Library` class is not concerned with getting information from the user.

Comment: This is what I came up with; is this better? In the `addBook()` method I put `Book btitle = new Book(title, author); btitle.assignID(); books.Add(btitle);`

Comment: @JustinL: that's pretty much it.

Answer (score -1):

Your constructor has to be the first method... You have "public void AssignId ()" as the first method... The compiler doesn't see your constructor... Move assignID underneath the constructor and your program will compile...

As for the remove method, simply traverse the list using the title or the isbn (your choice or both) and then list.remove...

Comment: Absolutely not true that the constructor has to be the first method.